# Can I say "nurture their pride in their country"?

Tags: word-usage

Is "nurture their pride in South Korea" a correct way to say? And, it is clear that "their" refers to early children?

> The result of this study revealed that most kindergarten teachers acknowledged the need for Korean history education in early childhood, and many said it was necessary to **nurture their pride in South Korea.**

Answer (score 1):

**Nurture their pride** is a completely reasonable phrase.  [You can find many examples of the phrase being used.](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22nurture%20their%20pride%22&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi6iNi2z87vAhXFFFkFHRklBRMQ_AUoAXoECAEQCw&biw=1306&bih=644)

But **their** is very unclear in this sentence.  There is no one in the sentence to whom *their* could refer other than the teachers.  Remember that "childhood" means "the condition or state of being a child"; it does not mean actual children.  The sentence would be much clearer if it were written like

> ...many said it was necessary to nurture **children's** pride in South Korea.

Answer (score 1):

Two possible subjects are introduced, which makes "nurture their pride" confusion.  The sentence likely means "nurture the children's pride" but it could also mean "nurture the kindergarten teacher's pride"

It is this ambiguity that makes the phrase awkward, but the use of "nurture their pride" is completely acceptable in scenarios where there isn't confusion about who's pride is being nurtured.

> The class learned South Korean History, to nurture their pride in South Korea.

Illustrates how "to nurture their pride" can be used without confusion, while the improper use

> The brother talked to his sister while the teacher stood in front of the class,
> to nurture their pride in South Korea.

Makes the sentence have even more choices for deciding who is the person (or persons) referred to by "their".